# python multiprocessing.Process‘s object name of class

Tags: python

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(5):
        p = Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
        p.start()
```

I  can't understand why python can create many same object name of class.

Comment: That's the purpose of a class. A class is a fingerprint for the thousands of objects you create. Think of it as a class named Human. We are all objects of this class. We are all Humans. Our names can also be repetitive. Here `p` is pointing to an object, everytime you create a new object, that pointers points to a new object.

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: Do you mean you don't know why you can store 5 different processes in `p`? You're _not_ -- at any given time, only at most one Process is bound to the name `p`. That doesn't mean the other Process objects don't exist in memory (should the class do the work to keep a registry of instances or otherwise make effort to prevent them from being garbage collected), but only one can be bound to the name `p` at a time.

Comment: Anyhow -- I had to guess at what you meant for my above comment, and I have no idea if the guess was correct. A better description of your problem would do a lot of good.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy  I think you understand the question I want to ask, sorry for my vague description of the question, and appreciate your answers

Answer (score 0):

Python doesn't *declare* variables like that, it creates *names* and then uses *reference counting* to account for how many names refer to an object

This works the other way too, for example a list with the names `a` and `b` can be modified via either

```py
>>> a = []
>>> b = a
>>> b.append(1)
>>> a
[1]
```

As even basic types are instances of objects, you can see this reference counting at work with even a humble `int`

```py
>>> import sys
>>> a = 1
>>> sys.getrefcount(1)
219
>>> b = 1
>>> sys.getrefcount(1)
220
>>> del a
>>> sys.getrefcount(1)
219
```

Take a look at **Python has "names"** from this now-ancient, but venerable article for a great description
https://david.goodger.org/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#python-has-names